# Truncate index_event does not work

Tags: magento-1.9, log

I want to truncate the table "index_event" but that does not work.

I get the following error:

```
Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`db_name`.`index_process_event`, CONSTRAINT `FK_INDEX_PROCESS_EVENT_EVENT_ID_INDEX_EVENT_EVENT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `db_name `.`index_event` (`event_id`))
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can `DELETE FROM index_event` to delete all entries with respect to foreign key constraints. But why do you want to do that? Maybe the solution to your actual problem is something else.

Answer (score 0):

TRUNCATE TABLE fails for an InnoDB table if there are any FOREIGN KEY constraints from other tables that reference the table.
In your sql query- 
 “index_event” and “index_process_event” are associated with the foreign key “event_id”

You can truncate the index_event by:

1. Removing the constraints
2. Perform Truncate
3. Delete manually the rows which have now no references
4. Create Constraints

Comment: Removing the constraints might result in a polluted database. I guess you can best just DELETE the records (so the cascading delete will be done) and then set the auto_increment value back to 1. This is basically the same as truncate. Or not. Please don't shoot me if I'm wrong ;-)

Comment: @GielBerkers `$con->dropForeignKey($table, $fkName)->truncateTable($table)->addForeignKey(...)` should work, but it doesn't. Do you have any ideas?